# regarding c++ typedef with templates

Tags: c++, typedef

I am trying to understand the meaning of following typedef

```
class A;

typedef bool (*TempType) (shared_ptr<A> s);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TempType` is a function pointer type taking a `shared_ptr<A>` argument and returning `bool`.

For example you could use it like that:

```
bool my_func(shared_ptr<A> s)
{
    return false;
}

// Variable x is of type TempType: A function pointer with a known signature.
TempType x = &my_func;
```

Comment: can you please give an example how to use this `x` as a function calling ?

Comment: To use `x` from Ferdinand's example in a call, remember that declaration reflects use: `bool result = (*x)(my_shared_ptr);`

Answer (score 2):

Declaration reflects use. You are defining a type called `TempType`. From the declaration, you see that it will be used as `bool (*TempType)(shared_ptr<A> s)`, which looks like a function call if `*TempType` were a function. If `*TempType` is a function, and declaration reflects use, our use of `TempType` is to dereference it with the dereferencing operator; so `TempType` is a pointer to a function. What type of function is it a pointer to? One that takes a `shared_ptr<A>` as an argument (said argument named `s`), and returns a bool.

In general, "declaration reflects use" is the secret to figuring out these type definitions, along with needing to just remember which type you're defining and which you're referring to. I try to avoid having two unbound names (in this case, `TempType` and `s`) in a definition, since it doesn't add much except for potential for confusion; `typedef bool (*TempType) (shared_ptr<A> s);` and `typedef bool (*TempType) (shared_ptr<A>);` have identical meaning.

Comment: +1. With more reasonable names than `TempType` and `s`, the unbound names could add valuable meaning (e.g., `bool (*VisitNode)(shared_ptr<Node> node)`).